# Fast boolean interaction matrix with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 integer vectors, one very long `document` (1E5 to 1E7 elements), and one rather short `query` (typically 5-8 elements). I want to create a 2D boolean matrix `(i, j)` that puts `1` where `document[i] == query[j]`, otherwise `0`. For example:

| Document \ Query | 5 | 2 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| ... |  |  |  |

Is there a fast way to do it with Numpy, that is without a Python loop ? (Using Pandas here is not an option)

Comment: Given that most of the elements of this matrix are 0, you may find it useful to use [sparse matricies](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) to represent this boolean matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just take advantage of numpy broadcasting:

```py
import numpy as np

document = np.random.randint(0, 5, (10,))
query = np.array([2, 3, 5])

(document[:, np.newaxis] == query)
```

Which prints:

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

I hope this answers your question!